# How can I check if the InfluxDB v2 is online and the credentials are valid using the InfluxDB client for java?

Tags: java, influxdb-2

I'm using the InfluxDB 2 client for Java, and I was wondering how I would check if the InfluxDB is online and if the given credentials are valid.

In [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) I used the .ping() function, but I can't seem to find such a function for the [influxdb-client-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an exact replacement for ping(), but you can use the REST endpoint /health instead. See: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/api/#operation/GetHealth

There is also a class you can use for this:

```
if (influxDb != null) {
    HealthCheck healthCheck = influxDb.health();
    if(healthCheck.getStatus() == StatusEnum.PASS) {
            // do what you want here
    }
}
```